# What is login Keychain "Accountsd"? How do I disable it?

Tags: keychain

I am using a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 with MacOS X 10.15.4. I cannot find this Keychain in the Keychain app.

[image]

Comment: Your question seems at odds with the picture. What keychain can you not find?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

See this website for various solutions:
https://www.macoszon.com/accountsd-wants-to-use-the-login-keychain/

Hope this will help solving your problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.